# Prove $\lim_{x\to3} x^2-2x+3 = 6$

Tags: real-analysis

This was the last concept we covered in class.  My teacher barely went over it.  The directions state to use the definition to prove this limit.  It does not say what definition to use though.  I am really confused and just do not know where to get started.

Comment: What is the value taken by $x^2-2x+3$ when you get closer and closer to $x=3$ ? Study the values for $x=3+\epsilon$ and make $\epsilon$ smaller and smaller. Use your pocket calculator and try 3.1, 3.01, 3.001...

Comment: If the limit is $6$ you must prove that for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ with: $|x-3|<\delta \implies |(x^2-2x+3)-6|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given. Our goal is to find a $\delta > 0 $ such that if $|x-3|< \delta$, then $| x^2 - 2x + 3 - 6 | < \epsilon $. We start finding a bound for $| x^2 - 2x + 3 - 6 |$.

$$ | x^2 - 2x + 3 - 6 | = | x^2 - 2x -3 | = |x-3||x+1| < \delta|x+1|$$

We want to bound $|x+1|$. The standard trick is to use the triangle inequality and suppose that $\delta < 1$.

$$ |x+1| = |x-3 + 4| \leq |x-3| + 4 < 5 $$

$$ \therefore \delta |x+1 | < 5 \delta = \epsilon \iff \delta = \frac{ \epsilon }{5} $$

Hence, if we choose $\delta = \min (1, \frac{\epsilon}{5}) $, we have the desired result.

Comment: Well, certainly the last displayed statement is not correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin The last statement looks fine to me.

Comment: First, if $\delta=\epsilon/5$, we do not have $5\delta<\epsilon$. Second, there is never an equality defining $\delta$; if $\delta>0$ works, then so does any $0<\delta'<\delta$.

Comment: Ok, so what do you want me do ted?